# Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected '('

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transforms

Hope someone knows what to do and can help me:

A function does this:

```
element.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', s);
if ('transform' in element.style) {
  element.style.transform = s;
} else if ('-ms-transform' in element.style) {
  element.style['-ms-transform'] = s;
} else if ('-webkit-transform' in element.style) {
  element.style['-webkit-transform'] = s;
}
```

where "s" is this: 
 `s = 'matrix(' + matrix.a + ',' + matrix.b + ',' + matrix.c + ',' + matrix.d + ',' + matrix.e + ',' + matrix.f + ')'`

It works perfect with this.
For hardware acceleration I want to add `+ ' translateZ(0)'` to "s".

After doing this I get the following error:

> Error: < g> attribute transform: Expected '(', "…39394) translateZ(0)".

I also tried it without the "+" and directly connected. Maybe someone know what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I changed "s" to: 
`s = 'matrix3d(' + matrix.a + ',' + matrix.b + ',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ',' + matrix.c + ',' + matrix.d + ',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ',' + 0 + ',' + 1 + ',' + 0 + ',' + matrix.e + ',' + matrix.f + ',' + 0 + ',' + 1 + ')';` because of an idea of a co-worker.

unfortunately same error:

> Error: < g> attribute transform: Expected '(', "matrix3d(2.03961675842…".

Comment: when using matrix you cannot append something else i guess

Comment: As @TemaniAfif mentioned, are you sure that you can append `translateZ()` behind the matrix?

Comment: @zeropublix no I'm not sure :/ i just read about it and they said it works. 'As of me not being a pro i'm not sure about this being the right approach.

Comment: ah, you should add the SVG tag ... now i see the `g` in the title

Comment: @TemaniAfif where to add the svg tag?

Comment: i meant in the question ;) i already did it so we know it's about SVG and not CSS only

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh than thanks :)

Comment: `setAttribute()` only takes two parameters, not three, so I'm not sure why it is working for you. It should be `element.setAttribute('transform', s);`

Comment: Yeah I saw this too, made a mistake here. I'm using: element.setAttributeNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the first line, where you set the attribute. `transform` attributes on SVG elements are a bit different from `transform` styles in CSS, and [they do not support `translateZ`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) All the stuff afterwards on `style.transform` should be fine.

Comment: Can you tell me what to change or is it just wrong and i can't do it like I think?

Comment: @breezertwo Why do you need the attribute, does the style not do the job by itself?

Comment: I don't get what you want to know from me. This whole thing is from a JS plugin. I have to use it like this. but because of being awfully slow on mobiles I want to try it wit enforced hardware acceleration and use 3D rendering.

Comment: @breezertwo AFAIK the `translateZ(0)` trick is only useful for elements which don't already have a transform. Your matrix transform should trigger hardware acceleration by itself.

Comment: Ah okay. I thought it's just triggered with matrix3d(...). But than the implementation is just slow and I can't do anything. thanks so far.

Comment: Dont waste your time on translateZ trick, modern browsers already learned how to apply hw accell via normal ways

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same error when I accidentally typed

```
.attr("transform", `matrix3d(${this.transformToArray(matrix)})`)
```

instead of

```
.style("transform", `matrix3d(${this.transformToArray(matrix)})`)
```

in D3. Note that the error doesn't have anything to do with the transformation but with the D3 function. Just to help the people using D3 and finding this post :)

Comment: For those like me who are about to spend an embarrassingly long time trying to figure out the difference between the two, one is `.attr(...)` and one is `.style(...)` - I was looking at the arguments, not the function name.

Answer (score 0):

So i know what my problem was. It's not possible to use anything in addition to `matrix()` or `matrix3d()`